# Error cannot import name 'dtensor' from 'tensorflow.compat.v2.experimental'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I can't start training my deep learning models anymore. This error is displayed every time:

```
cannot import name 'dtensor' from 'tensorflow.compat.v2.experimental' (C:\Users\Chica\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v2\experimental__init__.py)
```

Is this a problem that can be solved by "anaconda navigator"? If so, how can I solve it?

Comment: We need more info. Are you using the same version of tensorflow as before ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a incompatibility with tensorflow and kera pakages. Just try to install a specific version of tensorflow or downgrade keras executing:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.8
```

or downgrading keras executing:

```
pip install keras==2.6
```

Hope it works for you.